# Superset of fields in all documents in a collection Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

How to create a super set of fields(except `_id`) present in all the documents in a single collection of MongoDB assuming that all documents are of same type but different number of fields.

Example :

```
doc1 - {"_id":"test1", "firstName":"sample1", "age":24, "state":"Kansas"}
doc2 - {"_id":"test2", "lastName":"sample2", "age":24, "country":"US"}
```

Super set would be : `{"firstName", "lastName", "age", "state", "country"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running a `mapReduce` **operation that will return all the given document keys in the input collection** as the `_id` key of the resulting document. This will be in an output collection where you can then apply the distinct command on the `_id` field to retrieve the superset of the fields.

The example that follows shows this concept:

```
// Run mapReduce on collectionName
String map = "function () { for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); } }";
String reduce = "function () {}";
MapReduceResults<ValueObject> results = mongoTemplate.mapReduce(
    "collectionName", 
    map, 
    reduce,
    new MapReduceOptions().outputCollection("col_out"), 
    ValueObject.class
);
// Get the distinct keys from output collection col_out ---
List<String> fieldsSuperset = mongoTemplate.getCollection("col_out").distinct("_id");
```